# Creating site with subsite using webtemplate

Tags: web-template

I have webtemplate (not a site definition) which is an exported site. I want to create a subsite in this site. I want this to happen when a new site of this template is created. But I don't know how. I have the following problems:

- I've tried using a webeventreceiver, but I'm deploying to the bin so I can't use eventreceivers.
- I've tried using a siteprovisioningprovider but I don't know how and if it's even possible to link this to my webtemplate.
- For as far as I know it isn't possible to include a subsite in a template.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be this is not possible. I ended up creating the subsite in code when the parentsite is created. The big disadvantage is that if I want to create the site manually, I also have to create the subsite manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a feature that creates a site through code based on your specifications, and reference this feature in your webtemplate's onet.xml.

Comment: I know, but then I have to use a feature receiver. I can't use a feature receiver because I'm deploying to the bin.